# What are the best Banshee flying tactics?

Tags: halo-reach

What are the best Banshee flying tactics in Halo: Reach?

For example, should one use a certain evasive maneuver over another (e.g. the loop over the barrel roll)?

**EDIT.** Tips 5-8 in @murgatroid99's answer are what I had in mind (the rest are just "how to operate the banshee" instructions, not tactics), except that I was hoping for more advanced techniques. I've seen some Banshee drivers who are seemingly able to avoid all DMR fire, for example, and would like to know how they do it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to know about a particular situation? Are you just interested in evasive maneuvers?

Comment: Any Banshee flying tactics that would help one succeed with the Banshee. It's difficult to be more specific since I don't know what I don't know. I did not intend for my example to construe that I was interested just in evasive maneuvers.

Comment: If you have a specific question like the one you edited into your question, you should ask it as its own question.

Comment: Please explain. I don't see why this question isn't okay as is.

Comment: It's just as I said. If you want an answer to a specific question, ask that question. But don't tack it on to a question you already asked. As it is, I'm not sure if this question should stay open. It's pretty open ended and vague, as evidenced by the fact that I answered the question you wrote but not the one you were thinking of.

Comment: Because the question is not clear on what a tactic actually is, and what you're looking for. If you need to clarify your question after receiving answers that you don't want, consider perhaps maybe your original question isn't clear enough. "Tips and tricks" questions are usually avoided because there are infinitely possible answers for them. If you have a question specifically about "avoiding DMR fire", please ask that instead of asking for tips in general.

Comment: @YiJiang How do you know that there are infinitely many possible answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost and let off for a half second then shoot and backflip at the excact same time. Your bomb will travel much faster. Its called the torpedo shot. Ps constant boost flips will make it notoriously difficult for the enemy to hit you

Answer (score 2):

Some things to keep in mind when flying the Banshee:

1. There are two firing modes: you can switch weapons to switch between plasma rifle type fire (the default) and fuel rod fire (explosives). The fuel rod shots will home onto enemy vehicles like some of the infantry power weapons.
2. Do not run into solid terrain/environment. Like with any vehicle fast enough, you and the Banshee will take damage from such collisions.
3. The Banshee can boost with (I think) the grenade button.
4. The Banshee can also evade up or to the sides
5. It can often be useful to attack people by using a fuel rod shot and then immediately doing a back roll so that you almost immediately get another shot at the same point in case the first missed or did not kill your target.
6. Rockets can only do wide turns, so you can destroy a rocket by flying towards some solid terrain and then dodging so that the rocket cannot turn fast enough to keep from hitting the terrain.
7. Scorpion Tanks are major threats to Banshees, since their shells move extremely fast and kill a Banshee in one shot. Scorpions cannot look up above a certain angle, so you can fly over one to keep it from tracking you. A single fuel rod shot to the gun should disable it.
8. In general, dodge often. It makes you much harder to hit and is well worth the momentary disorientation.

Besides these, simply follow general Halo tactics: try to shoot people, especially the ones that are shooting you.

Comment: Thanks. Notice that I've edited my question because of your answer.